# How to embed Instagram video in SilverStripe content editor

Tags: instagram, silverstripe

In SilverStripe I would like to embed an Instagram video in a HTMLEditorField.

I have written the following code in `_config.php` to allow me to add `<script>` tags in the editor but the editor is still not accepting the script tags.

```
HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->setOption('extended_valid_elements', 'script[language|type|src]');
HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->setOption('verify_html', 'false');
```

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most robust solution would be to create a video [shortcode](http://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/extending/shortcodes/) (or specialized Instagram video shortcode) where you just parse the ID of the video and it renders the required HTML for you out of a template.

This will look like:

```
[InstagramVideo id=12345]
```

This way you can easily update all embedded videos later.

Using [shortcodable module](https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-shortcodable) you can make an easy to use dialog for adding the shortcode to your $Content HTML.

There is already a [module for a youtube shortcode](https://github.com/gordonbanderson/weboftalent-youtube) which can get you started.